# Can I use a "Counter Target Spell" on Enchantments?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can I use a Counter Target Spell on enchantments? Enchantments are considered spells right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Spells are anything that you cast from your hand and add to the stack. Lands and abilities are not spells.

> A spell is a card on the stack. As the first step of being cast (see
>   rule 601, "Casting Spells"), the card becomes a spell and is moved to
>   the top of the stack from the zone it was in, which is usually its
>   owner's hand. (See rule 405, "Stack.") A spell remains on the stack as
>   a spell until it resolves (see rule 608, "Resolving Spells and
>   Abilities"), **is countered (see rule 701.5)**, or otherwise leaves the
>   stack. For more information, see section 6, "Spells, Abilities, and
>   Effects."

So you can counter an enchantment as long as it is on the stack (not resolved).

Lands are not spells and are not put on the stack, so they cannot be countered. Abilities however **are** put on the stack, but they can only be countered by spells which say they can counter abilities.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys.....So I can counter an enchantment even though it is not summoned and an enchantment can use it's ability right away?

Comment: When you mean "not summoned" as in put onto the battlefield without casting it but for example by an effect (eg Academy Rector), you cannot counter it. When you cast an enchantment spell (pay its costs, put on the stack etc), it usually can be countered.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear what you're asking about.
No, if you really do mean Enchantments.
Yes, if you mean Enchantment cards being cast.

---

A spell is a card or copy of a card on the stack is a spell.

> 111.1. A spell is a card on the stack. [...]

> 111.1a A copy of a spell is also a spell, [...]

The type of the card is of no consequence. If there's an Enchantment card on the stack (e.g. because it's currently being cast), it's a spell, it can be targeted as a spell, and it can be countered.

But you asked about "Enchantments". I'm not sure if you realize that "Enchantments" refers to "Enchantments cards or tokens on the battlefield". This is also what many people are asking about when they ask about countering Enchantments.

Cards (or tokens) on the battlefield aren't on the stack, so they aren't spells. They are permanents, and you would require [Naturalize](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Naturalize) (for example) to get rid of one.

Answer (score 3):

If it is being cast, yes. If it is one the field already, no. Pretty much everything is a spell before it becomes a permanent. When you cast an enchantment, it is put on the stack as an enchantment spell. When it resolves, it becomes an enchantment permanent on the field. Same with Creatures. The only type of card that can't be a spell is "land". Also of note is that cards are only spells when they are cast. If they are simply put onto the field, without being cast, they are never spells.

Comment: abilities go on the stack and cannot be countered with a counter spell. this answer could be improved by mentioning that they can only be countered when cast and not while they are already on the battlefield.

Comment: Re "Pretty much everything is a spell before it becomes a permanent." Well that's not true. It's very common to place cards on the 'field without casting them.